# Pointer-arithmetic on contiguous non-array objects

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

`std::vector` is generally considered to be unimplementable pre-C++20 (as discussed in [P0593](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html)), as the elements cannot be placed in an internal array while adhering to the required performance restrictions, and pointer-arithmetic on returned pointers and in particular the pointer returned by `.data()` not being allowed:

```
char * storage = new char[sizeof(int) * 3];
int * data = new(storage) int(1);
new(storage + sizeof(int)) int(2);
new(storage + sizeof(int) * 2) int(3);

data[2] = 5; // undefined behavior, as there is no array of int at the address data points to
```

However, the pre-C++17 standard contains these quotes:

> [basic.compound] If an object of type T is located at an address A, a pointer of type cv T* whose value is the address A is said to point to that object, regardless of how the value was obtained.

> [expr.add] For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.

> [expr.add] Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object.

This should make the following code legal and conforming:

```
char * storage = new char[sizeof(int) * 3];
int * data = new(storage) int(1);
new(storage + sizeof(int)) int(2);
new(storage + sizeof(int) * 2) int(3);

int * tmp = data + 1; // legal due to [expr.add]
                      // tmp now points to the int placed at storage + sizeof(int) due to [basic.compound]
                      // requires laundering as of C++17
tmp = tmp + 1;        // tmp now points to the int placed at storage + sizeof(int) * 2
*tmp = 5;

(data + 1)[1] = 5;    // equivalent to the above
```

In other words, contiguously stored objects of the same type can reach each other so long as the pointers used to do so are only repeatedly moved step-wise to their immediate neighbour instead of using direct pointer arithmetic. Am I reading the standard correctly?

The C++17 standard changes the formulation of [basic.compound] and [expr.add] and requires laundering the pointer after each stepwise movement in order to actually point to the int object at that location, but should otherwise work equivalently.

---

Edited to remove the use of reinterpret_cast, as the legality of its use is not the focus of this question.

Comment: _"generally considered to be unimplementable pre-C++20"_  - wait, what? _"...as the elements cannot be placed in an internal array while adhering to the required performance restrictions, and pointer-arithmetic on returned pointers and in particular the pointer returned by .`data()` not being allowed"_ - ...but such arithmetic is guaranteed to work, right? Who says it's not allowed?

Comment: @TedLyngmo - the standard said it. Due to a (pretty big) language defect, there wasn't an array-of-`int` *object* created in that storage. Pointer arithmetic requires an array object. C++20's implicit object lifetimes are what fixed it (by ratifying, to an extent, what compilers already pretty much did).

Comment: @nlsbgr Please edit your question and put that very good link in it.

Comment: _regardless of how the value was obtained_ This was added to fix https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/73.html, the reading that one can craft a pointer to an object out of nothing (like, by reading bits from `/dev/random`) was barely intended

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: What is wrong with saying that pointer values whose provenance is unknown must be presumed capable of aliasing any pointers whose values have leaked?  In most cases where one could benefit from assuming pointers won't alias, a compiler could either know everything that has been with one of the pointers, or know that the other one was formed from something that can't alias the former.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: A compiler that recognizes concepts of leakage and unknown provenance will be able to handle tough corner cases 100% reliably (even if sub-optimally), while those which try to assume they can fully analyze everything are, so far as I can tell, invariably buggy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that code is perfectly legal even with c++20.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true
>
> - AliasedType and DynamicType are similar.
> - AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType.
> - AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17) char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

In

```
int * data = reinterpret_cast<int *>(storage);
```

the DynamicType is `char` and the AliasedType is `int` which fits none of the criteria. Even if the pointer arithmetic is allowed the `*tmp = 5;` still has to follow the type aliasing rules of the initial pointer.

To access the `int` you create via placement new you have to capture it's pointer:

```
int * p = new(storage) int(1);
```

But that isn't an array so you can't do pointer arithmetic (<= C++17) on it to get to the second ìnt`.

PS: Note that a `char *` with the value of the address of storage and an `int *` with the value of the address of storage may not be represented by the same bit pattern in the hardware.

Comment: I believe this does not apply as an object of type `int` has infact been constructed at the address in question via placement-new, so DynamicType - the type of the actual object being accessed - is `int` in this case.

Comment: @nlsbgr You need to call `std::launder` to get a pointer to the `int` object from the pointer to the `char` object or use the result of the `new` expression as shown in this answer. However, this answer is wrong in that pointer arithmetic on `p` is allowed due to implicit object creation. In fact the `new` is not required at all.

Comment: @user17732522 I addressed that in the last paragraph, the code examples explicitly referred to pre-C++17.

Comment: @nlsbgr Yes, but the answer is about C++20 (for some reason).

Comment: @nlsbgr The type aliasing rules do not allow that. The reinterpret_cast allows casting a pointer back to it's original type but the original type is `char`. The fact that an object of type `int` now lives at that address doesn't come into play in reinterpret_cast, only the type of the pointer is mentioned.

Comment: @user17732522 I corrected the pointer arithmetic part, that's allowed in C++20 now. The part about reinterpret_cast and type aliasing applies to all versions though I think. But proof me wrong.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The question is precisely asking whether that really is correct in all circumstances prior to C++17, because as quoted, prior to C++17 the standard considered pointer values to be determined by their address. There was no difference between pointing to one object or another at the same address.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I edited the question to avoid the reinterpret_cast, as the validity of the reinterpret_cast is besides the point of this question.

Comment: @nlsbgr That invalidates my answer then.

Comment: @user17732522: Both clang and gcc have for years treated the construct `if (p1==p2) *p1 = something;` as being valid only in cases where *both* `p1` and `p2` would be legitimately usable to access the object in question.  I'm not sure it matters what the Standard says if compiler writers can't be bothered to follow it.

Comment: @supercat Just because something is UB doesn't mean it can't give the right answer. There are also things that can not be implemented inside the C++ standard (e.g. new before c++20) that must use implementation defined behavior like comparing the address contained in incompatible pointers. If compilers are too strict then there wouldn't be a c++.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: My point is that clang and gcc perform optimizing transforms which on some rare occasions break constructs which whose behavior is defined by the Standard as written.  The maintainers of clang and gcc have received simple programs where the transforms are performed inappropriately, but don't want to limit their optimizations to those that are actually allowable by the Standard.  The question of whether a construct is defined by the Standard is thus orthogonal to the question of whether clang and/or gcc should be relied upon to process it meaningfully.

Comment: @supercat There are 3 cases to consider: 1) `p1` and `p2` are legally the same object so `p1 == p2`. 2) `p1` and `p2` are pointers to different parts of an array or similar block of memory allowing the equality test. Then `p1 != p2` and `something` isn't executed. 3) `p1` and `p2` are not equatable, that's UB. the compiler can do whatever. Even if `p1` and `p2` represent the same address.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: If `p1` is a pointer to an object, and `p2` is a pointer which points just past the previous object, the C++ Standard would characterize the result of the comparison as unspecified, allowing a compiler to arbitrarily execute the `*p1 = something;` or not, at its leisure, but any particular invocation would be required to either leave `*p1` holding its old value, or correctly handle the storage of the new value.  Both clang and gcc would sometimes perform the assignment without allowing for the possibility that it might affect the object whose address was stored in `p1`.

Comment: @supercat That is covered by case **3**. The compiler can do **whatever**. That's is what the standard says and the compilers are following the standard exactly. You are assuming the code would so something meaningful after an UB which simply is not true.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: The draft 7.3.10(3.1) says that in the case at issue, "the result of the comparison is unspecified".  It does *not* say that the behavior is Undefined.  That means that the comparison may report the values equal, or it may report the values unequal, but it does not grant compilers permission to treat any individual comparison in a manner that isn't consistent with one of the above choices.  What part of the Standard would grant compilers permission to deviate from that?

Comment: @supercat If you want a language lawyer answer about `if (p1==p2) *p1 = something;` then pleas open a new question.